# Unable to link against boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost, g++, ubuntu-14.04, boost-coroutine

I can't get my g++ to compile and link a minimal boost co-routine program (and I guess other components as well) on my machine.

```
// example.cpp

#include <boost/coroutine/all.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace boost::coroutines;

void mycorofunc(coroutine<void>::push_type &sink){
  std::cout << "1";
  sink();
  std::cout << " 3";
}

int main() {
  coroutine<void>::pull_type source{mycorofunc};
  std::cout << " 2";
  source();
  std::cout << " 4!" << std::endl;
}
```

I used apt-get to install boost (libboost-all-dev), but neither

```
g++ example.cpp -lboost_coroutine -lboost_system
```

nor

```
g++ example.cpp -I/usr/include -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lboost_coroutine -lboost_system
```

works. g++'s output is as follows:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/coroutine/v1/coroutine.hpp:19:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/coroutine/coroutine.hpp:13,
                 from /usr/include/boost/coroutine/all.hpp:11,
                 from example.cpp:3:
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/function_traits.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::function_traits<void>’:
example.cpp:7:31:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/function_traits.hpp:168:8: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct boost::detail::function_traits_helper<void*>’
 struct function_traits : 
        ^
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/function_traits.hpp:21:36: error: declaration of ‘struct boost::detail::function_traits_helper<void*>’
 template<typename Function> struct function_traits_helper;
                                    ^
example.cpp:7:31: error: ‘arity’ is not a member of ‘boost::function_traits<void>’
 void mycorofunc(coroutine<void>::push_type &sink){
                               ^
example.cpp:7:31: error: template argument 2 is invalid
example.cpp:7:44: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
 void mycorofunc(coroutine<void>::push_type &sink){
                                            ^
example.cpp: In function ‘void mycorofunc(int)’:
example.cpp:9:8: error: ‘sink’ was not declared in this scope
   sink();
        ^
example.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
example.cpp:14:17: error: ‘arity’ is not a member of ‘boost::function_traits<void>’
   coroutine<void>::pull_type source{mycorofunc};
                 ^
example.cpp:14:17: error: template argument 2 is invalid
example.cpp:14:30: error: expected initializer before ‘source’
   coroutine<void>::pull_type source{mycorofunc};
                              ^
example.cpp:16:10: error: ‘source’ was not declared in this scope
   source();
```

Some more information about my environment:

```
$$ locate coroutine/all.hpp
/usr/include/boost/coroutine/all.hpp
/usr/local/boost_1_58_0/boost/coroutine/all.hpp

$$ locate boost_system
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.54.0

$$ locate boost_coroutine
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_coroutine.a

$$ g++ -E -x c++ - -v < /dev/null  # printing g++ include path 
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1plus -E -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -fstack-protector -Wformat -Wformat-security
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/4.8
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8
 /usr/include/c++/4.8/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "<stdin>"
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
```

Compiler: have tried both g++ (v. 4.8.2) and g++-5

Distro: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Comment: code is fine: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/JIGaHPluYlDbZJRM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After days of debugging, this is the solution I found. It is possible that even a subset of the following instructions is equally enough to go about the problem.

### Quick instructions without much detail

Perform the following instructions:

1. Install `g++-6` (any version newer than `5.2` which supports `c++14` will
   most likely work as well, though I have not tested them).
2. Install boost `1.58` or newer (support for coroutine2). As of the date of
   this post, the latest version available in Ubuntu PPA is
   `1.54`. Therefore, you need to **manually** install boost. If you do not know how, follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24086375/532573).
3. Run your program using `-std=c++14` flag. Also, if you are working with coroutines like me, make sure to link against `libboost_context`. I have noticed that for coroutines *2*, `libboost_system` is not needed, perhaps because it is automally pulled in by `libboost_context`, though I'm not sure about the reason.
4. Make sure that you link against your newly installed boost libraries, and not the old one. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031869/linking-error-undefined-reference-about-boost-static-library-during-compiling) to see what might go wrong. In my case, I had to delete all the previously installed boost from my machines.

To put these points together, here's the command I used to compile and link my code (let's say I install boost in `/usr/local/`):

`g++-6 -std=c++14 example.cpp  -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_coroutine -lboost_context -lboost_system`

### More details

Apparently, `boost.coroutine` library in boost `1.54` is implemented with the deprecated C-like fcontext-API from boost.context [[source](http://coroutine%20is%20implemented%20with%20the%20deprecated%20C-like%20fcontext-API%20from%20boost.context)]. I have noticed that my machine had problem compiling those parts. Unfortunately, Ubuntu PPA does not offer any newer version than `1.54` at this moment. `Boost.coroutine2` is the recommended library to use, which can be found in version `1.59` or newer. Therefore, you need to manually download a suitable version of boost from its website and install it.

After doing so, my code successfully *compilied*, but not *linked*:

```
... undefined reference to `ontop_fcontext'  `boost::context::basic_fixedsize_stack<boost::context::stack_traits>::deallocate(boost::context::stack_context&)':
example.cpp:(...): undefined reference to `boost::context::stack_traits::minimum_size()'
example.cpp:(...): undefined reference to `boost::context::stack_traits::is_unbounded()'
example.cpp:(...): undefined reference to `boost::context::stack_traits::maximum_size()'
```

Surprisingly, adding `-lboost_context` flag to the compile command did not remove this link error, suggesting that `libboost_context` is not properly linked against.

I then came across [a question](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2016/03/228703.php) in boost forum wherein the original poster had somewhat similar problem to what I had. In short, there are a number of C macros that prevent execution_context to be properly included, and thus the problem with `libboost_context`. The code to know if your compiler has some of these macros enabled is as follows (I'm not sure if *all* of these macros are relevant):

```
#include <boost/config.hpp> 

#if defined(BOOST_NO_CXX11_AUTO_DECLARATIONS) || \
     defined(BOOST_NO_CXX11_CONSTEXPR) || \
     defined(BOOST_NO_CXX11_DEFAULTED_FUNCTIONS) || \
     defined(BOOST_NO_CXX11_FINAL) || \
     defined(BOOST_NO_CXX11_HDR_TUPLE) || \
     defined(BOOST_NO_CXX11_NOEXCEPT) || \
     defined(BOOST_NO_CXX11_NULLPTR) || \
     defined(BOOST_NO_CXX11_RVALUE_REFERENCES) || \
     defined(BOOST_NO_CXX11_TEMPLATE_ALIASES) || \
     defined(BOOST_NO_CXX11_UNIFIED_INITIALISATION_SYNTAX) || \
     defined(BOOST_NO_CXX11_VARIADIC_TEMPLATES) || \
     defined(BOOST_NO_HDR_ATOMIC) || \
     defined(BOOST_NO_HDR_TUPLE)
#error "execution_context is prevented to be included in this compiler"; 
#endif
```

The solution is easy: installing `g++-6` (or I *guess* `5.2` or newer), and compiling the code with `std=-c++14`.

Comment: My 5 cents. Faced the same problem. It was solved by linkage order, just placed the `context` AFTER the `fiber` in CMake's `FIND_PACKAGE`