# Link against boost coroutine

Tags: c++, linux, boost, linker

```
#include <boost/coroutine/all.hpp>
using namespace boost::coroutines;

void cooperative(coroutine<void>::push_type &sink){}

int main()
{
  coroutine<void>::pull_type source{cooperative};
  return 0;
}
```

compiling with `g++ -lboost_coroutine main.cpp -o main`

I get a lot of output with `undefined reference` errors.

undefined reference to: `boost::coroutines::stack_traits::default_size()` `boost::coroutines::detail::coroutine_context()` `boost::coroutines::stack_traits::minimum_size()` `boost::coroutines::stack_traits::is_unbounded()`
and so on

Boost version: 1.71.0
OS: Xubuntu 20.04

If necessary, I will provide a complete list with linker errors

Comment: Try putting `-lboost_coroutine` after .cpp

Comment: @user7860670 yes, now there are no errors

Comment: @RHertel Not entirely. The correct answer is above: "Try putting -lboost_coroutine after .cpp"

Comment: @ibse The error appears to be the same as the one you describe, and the same library is linked. Please see points 2 and 3 of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34055728/4770166).